# Is there a way to tell FileZilla to not upload files and directories that begin with a dot?

Tags: filezilla

When I upload my PHP sites created in Eclipse to my website via FileZilla, I first have to:

- select all
- then individually unselect all dot files and directories since I don't want this information on the server

**Is there a way I can tell FileZilla not to upload these dot files and directories by default?**

[image]